# Special Pasting JSON As Class does not recognize the request data structure

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am creating a class using *Paste Special* for a JSON request response like this:

```
{
  "status": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    "key5": "value5",
    ...
  },
  "message": "success"
}
```

And the key-value pairs can be up to 50.

Paste Special has a problem mapping this data structure into a class. It returns the following code:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string key1 { get; set; }
    public string key2 { get; set; }
    public string key3 { get; set; }
    public string key4 { get; set; }
    public string key5 { get; set; }
}
```

Knowing the number of keys can vary, what is the correct way to write a class?

Comment: use a dictionary, eg Status is a Dictionary<string, string>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json in `status` can be represented by `Dictionary<string, string>`.  You can define your class like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5qTi6M